# Rationalizing Numerical Output

Tags: wolfram-mathematica

Consider :

```
Grid@Partition[
     Text[Style[ToString[Range[0, 180, 22.5][[#]]] <> "\[Degree]", Bold, 16,
          GrayLevel[(8 - #)/10]]] & /@ Range[8], 2, 1]
```

[image]

How can I get rid of the dot following the Integers ?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If a number becomes an integer when you rationalize it, use the integer; otherwise stick with the original number. This is achieved by a simple function, `f[x]`:

```
f[x_] := If[IntegerQ[n = Rationalize[x]], n, x]
```

Testing...

```
f[67.5]
f[0.]
f[45.]

(* Out  *)
67.5
0
45
```

You can't just `Rationalize` all the values, as the following makes clear:

[image: rationalize]

To see how it works in your case, just insert `(f/@)` into your code to reformat the values output from `Range`:

```
Grid@Partition[
Text[Style[
  ToString[(f/@ Range[0, 180, 22.5])[[#]]] <> "\[Degree]", 
  Bold, 16, GrayLevel[(8 - #)/10]]] & /@ Range[8], 2, 1]
```

So

[image: temps]

Comment: Thank You, combining with sodas I think N@Rationalize@ any number should do it ?

Comment: @500 N@Rationalize@<any number> does not quite solve it, because `N` undoes the results by converting the integer (returned by `Rationalize`) back to a real number! E.g.  `N[Rationalize[45.]]` returns "45." as the result.

Comment: re: edit, good catch ;-)  I didn't notice it when I voted for this a few minutes ago.

Answer (score 9):

Although the original question doesn't have any numbers with exponents, it would be safest in general to use NumberForm as follows:

```
trimPoint[n_] := 
NumberForm[n, 
 NumberFormat -> (DisplayForm@
  RowBox[Join[{StringTrim[#1, RegularExpression["\\.$"]]}, 
    If[#3 != "", {
      "\[Times]", SuperscriptBox[#2, #3]}, {}]]
   ] &)]
```

Then you only have to modify the original code by inserting //trimPoint as follows:

```
Grid@Partition[
 Text[Style[
  ToString[Range[0, 180, 22.5][[#]] // trimPoint] <> "\[Degree]", 
  Bold, 16, GrayLevel[(8 - #)/10]]] & /@ Range[8], 2, 1]
```

Answer (score 6):

Another possibility is not to generate them in the first place.

```
If[IntegerQ[#], #, N@#] & /@ Range[0, 180, 45/2]
```

giving

> {0, 22.5, 45, 67.5, 90, 112.5, 135, 157.5, 180}

Answer (score 5):

In general, you should use [`Rationalize`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Rationalize.html).

```
Rationalize@10.
Out[1] = 10
```

However in your case, you shouldn't simply use `Rationalize`, as you don't want to operate on some of the elements. Here's a simple approach that will do what you want.

```
list = Range[0, 180, 22.5] /. (x_ /; FractionalPart@x == 0.) -> 
   IntegerPart@x
Grid@Partition[
  Text[Style[ToString[list[[#]]] <> "\[Degree]", Bold, 16, 
      GrayLevel[(8 - #)/10]]] & /@ Range[8], 2, 1]
```

[image]

The code above generates the same list as yours, and then *conditionally* replaces those elements which have a [`FractionalPart`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/FractionalPart.html?q=FractionalPart&lang=en) equal to `0.` (e.g., `10.`), with its [`IntegerPart`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/IntegerPart.html) (e.g. `10`).

Comment: There can be problems with this approach, e.g. `AccountingForm[
 1500000*0.675 /. (x_ /; FractionalPart@x == 0.) -> IntegerPart@x]`

Comment: @ChrisDegnen You're right. I didn't think through cases where it'd fail, and only tested the OP's case. Thanks for pointing it out :)

Comment: You're welcome. Binary representation means care needs to be taken using IntegerPart and FractionalPart, e.g. `x = 6250*0.292; {x, IntegerPart[x], IntegerPart[Round[x, 10.^-6]]}` yields {1825., 1824, 1825}

Answer (score 4):

Another option is to remove any trailing `"."` using `StringTrim`:

```
Grid@Partition[
  Text[Style[
      StringTrim[ToString[Range[0, 180, 22.5][[#]]], "."] <> "\[Degree]", 
    Bold, 16, GrayLevel[(8 - #)/10]]] & /@ Range[8], 2, 1]
```